# vQmod permission error on local server

Tags: php, opencart

I'm new to OpenCart and having this error on my local wamp server and also checked at `index.php` file  properties it is showing permission. How can I resolve this problem?

Below is error which is showing me on screen:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /opencart-development/open-cart/vqmod-2.4.1-opencart/ on this server.

Comment: AFTER GOING TO (http://localhost/opencart-development/open-cart/vqmod-2.4.1-opencart/vqmod/install/) NOW I SEE

Comment: index.php not writeable
Administrator index.php not writeable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to install vqmod correctly in you local server. If you are extract vqmod-2.4.1-opencart.zip than you can see vqmod folder in vqmod-2.4.1-opencart folder.

So you need to copy that vqmod folder to your local server and need to run following url to install vqmod :

http://www.yoursite.com/vqmod/install/index.php